# Database sql server with results but view is empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

something really strange is happening. So I have a table named Lactinfo_News with 1 row. I've created also a view called LACTINFO_VW_LatestNews which have "SELECT * FROM Lactinfo_News" and is returning the same 1 row.

[image]

I'm using Eloquent and In my news Manager I have,

```
public function GetLatestNews($rowsPerPage) {
        $list = DB::table('LACTINFO_VW_LatestNews')
            ->orderBy('RegistedDate', 'DESC')
            ->paginate($rowsPerPage);

        return $list;
    }

where $rowsPerPage = 30.
```

In my controller I have,

```
// >> current page
$page = '1';
if (! empty ( $request->query ( 'page' ) )) {
$page = $request->query ( 'page' );
}

// >> search
$nM = new NewsManager();
$list = $nM->GetLatestNews($page, $this->nbOfRowsPage);

return view ('admin.news.index', [
                'results' => compact($list),
                'page' => $page,
                'startDate' => $startDate,
                'endDate'=>$endDate 
        ] );
    }
```

And in my view,

```
<table id="news-results" class="hover responsive" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="column">Título</th>          
            <th scope="column">Descrição</th>
            <th scope="column">Data Início</th>
            <th scope="column">Ficheiro</th>
            <th scope="column">Registada em</th>
            <th scope="column">Criada por</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @if (count($results) > 0) 
            @foreach ($results as $r)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $r->title }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $r->description }}</td>
                    <td>{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($r->startDate)->format('d/m/Y') }}</td> 
                    <td>{{ $r->fileURL }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $r->registedDate }}</td>     
                    <td>{{ $r->createdBy }}</td>            
                </tr>
            @endforeach

        @else
            <tr><td colspan="11">Não existem notícias criadas</td></tr>
        @endif
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If I dump the $results var is empty..

What's happening? This is really strange :S I don't think I need to execute any artisan command because I've add a new function to my manager but I'm stuck with this problem for a few days...

Comment: try `compact('list')` instead of `compact($list)`

Comment: Nothing, I've done {{dd($results)}} and inside my array list the query key have []...

Comment: if you `dd($list);` in your controller after this line `$list = $nM->GetLatestNews($page, $this->nbOfRowsPage);`. there is some data in the $list variable?

Comment: https://ibb.co/kG1WhWm is the same

Comment: try returning the variable without the compact `'results' => $list,`

Comment: Undefined property: stdClass::$title (View:

Comment: Ok, better, results is there in the view. In your object is title or Title? if it's Title use `$r->Title` and the same for the others

Comment: Is that!! Thanks a lot man!! I will update my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `compact` on an object of type [LengthAwarePaginator](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html), which is kind of weird IMHO.

Why don't you pass `$list` in your view?

Comment: I'm doing this because I've received the error Undefined property: stdClass::$title (View) and one of the solutions was this..

Comment: just `dump($r)` in your foreach and look at the object you have. Maybe you have misspelled the capitalization of your property

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in the Controller and in my View,

So I've changed my controller return to

```
return view ('admin.news.index', [
                'results' => $list,
                'page' => $page,
                'startDate' => $startDate,
                'endDate'=>$endDate
        ] );
```

And in my view I wasnt calling in a wrong way my parameters...

```
<tbody>
        @if (count($results) > 0) 
            @foreach ($results as $r)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $r->Title }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $r->Description }}</td>
                    <td>{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($r->StartDate)->format('d/m/Y') }}</td> 
                    <td>{{ $r->fileURL }}</td>
                    <td>{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($r->RegistedDate)->format('d/m/Y') }}</td>      
                    <td>{{ $r->refCredential }}</td>            
                </tr>
            @endforeach

        @else
            <tr><td colspan="11">Não existem notícias criadas</td></tr>
        @endif
    </tbody>
```